# visual studio .net core web development - how to fully turn off caching on my desk

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

While developing, i need to readily edit js files in the wwwroot subfolders of my .net core. But when i make edits, despite clearing browser cach or stop and re - run the old JS files are still found. How can i force iisexpress(?) to always look to the real current files?   I see some web.config options but how does this work with .net core?

Comment: Are you **sure** it's IIS Express caching them and not your browser? Do you have static-file-compression enabled?

Comment: in Chrome browser cache clear or CTRL reload is not clearing it , altering path in wwwroot of the subfolder is how i keep working painfully

Comment: I tried to add in Program.cs:        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append(
                    //"Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cacheMaxAgeOneWeek}");
                    "Cache-Control", $"public, no-cache");
        }
    });

Comment: When I switched to .NET 6 I started having this issue. Worked fine on .NET 5. Would love to know if you solved this.